# Filter look-up collection with date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

How to filter the looked-up collection with the date range? I have tried many ways but not able to get the desire results.

Below is my code so far

```
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "leaves",
          localField: "_leaves",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "leaves"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          ....
          leaves: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$leaves",
              as: "leave",
              cond: [
                {
                  $and: [
                    { $gt: ["$$leave.date", start] 
                 },
                    { $lt: ["$$leave.date", end] }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

Update 1

Sorry for not being clear enough..

Leaves Collection

```
    {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),,
            "_takenBy": ObjectId("..."),
            "date": ISODate("2017-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
            ...
    },
    {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),,
            "_takenBy": ObjectId("..."),
            "date": ISODate("2017-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
            ...
    }
    {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),,
            "_takenBy": ObjectId("..."),
            "date": ISODate("2017-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            ...
    }

    Expected Result:
    {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),,
            "_takenBy": ObjectId("..."),
            "date": ISODate("2017-04-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
            ...
    },
    {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),,
            "_takenBy": ObjectId("..."),
            "date": ISODate("2017-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
            ...
    }

    So, I have tried to "unwind" and "match" the leaves collection after "lookup"

    {
            $lookup: {
            from: "leaves",
            localField: "_leaves",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "leaves"
            }
    },
    { $unwind: "$leaves" },
    {
            $match: {
            "leaves.date": {
            $gt: range.start.toDate(),
            $lt: range.end.toDate()
            }
    }
    },
```

When I tried to "project" it, it only returns one leave record instead of two, 
I did tried to "group" but not sure how to group the others collection 
like shifts collection after the lookup

```
    {
            $project: {
            user: 1
            leaves: 1
            shifts: 1
    //     }
```

Comment: It's actually a lot more efficient to `$unwind` and `$match` after a `$lookup`, since those following stages are actually "rolled up" into the `$lookup` itself and the query condition is actually run against the foreign collection **before** results are returned. You can see this in the explain output when you add that option to the aggregate command.

Comment: As for your "general" question though, since you tagged the question with mongoose, I think you have been spoilt a little and are used to just submitting "plain strings" as arguments for looking up "dates". This does not work in the aggregation framework as it does for queries with `.find()` with mongoose, because in an aggregation pipeline, document shape changes and the schema no longer applies. This means **autocasting** no longer happens. Just like `ObjectId`, you need to manually cast to `Date` in order to match.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your suggestion. How can I achieve it? I did tried to unwind and match it but I only get one result.           { $unwind: "$leaves" },
          {
            $match: {
              "leaves.date": {
                $gt: range.start.toDate(),
                $lt: range.end.toDate()
              }
            }
          },$project: {
          ....
          leaves: 1
          }

Comment: You need to actually show some data and the result you expect to achieve. If we cannot see the problem, then we cannot solve it. So there should be enough data provided to be able to produce a minimal result.

Comment: @NeilLunn, sorry for not being clear enough. I have updated my question with the data and expected result as well as what I have done so far. Hope you get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: You are still not explaining your problem. What are the dates you are actually supplying? Show the code! I presume these are momentjs objects given the `.toDate()` methods but you need to show the actual code and supplied values you are using. If that's the expected result then what are you actually getting? But showing the values should make that clear. Also please to not obfuscate `ObjectId` values. If it's a foreign key then show the parent document and if you don't actually show the `ObjectId` values then just use an integer. But I still fail to understand why so many people remove it